# What is the easiest way to backup PostgreSQL and send backups to Google Drive?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am new with PostgreSQL, So my question is: what is the easiest way to make regular backups and send them to Google Drive. Perhaps, there is a tool that can make it or something else.

Comment: If you are looking for a tool to backup PostgreSQL databases automatically and send backups to Google Drive, you definitely have to try PostgreSQL-Backup http://postgresql-backup.com/

Comment: Perhaps https://rclone.org/, a command line program which will send data to any of the cloud providers, including Google Drive.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

to send your pg_dump output to Dropbox. I got this by Googling [script load file dropbox](https://www.google.ie/search?q=script%20load%20file%20dropbox&oq=script%20load%20file%20dropbox&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l3.24222j0j4&client=tablet-android-lenovo&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8). You may find some of the other scripts more to your liking.

Remember the dba's motto - **backup or f*ckup** and test, test and test again. Personally, I would recommend a local (speed of recovery) **and** remote (double-sure) copy (as the Americans say, "belt and suspenders").

It is a bash tool, but then I always assume `PostgreSQL`ers are on a decent operating system :-).

**Update** - the bash shell can now be used natively on Windows as well since Microsoft appear to be doing more embracing and less smothering of *nix tools!

Answer (score 2):

I use [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) (follow the installation and set-up guidelines from the link).

Once gdrive is installed, I dump my own databases to a `/bak` folder daily, and then upload my files to Google Drive's PGBAK folder using gdrive. I use the following script in /etc/cron.daily/:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
BAK=/bak

# backup globals (database names, users, etc)
# get id of PGBAK folder
PGBAK="`gdrive list --no-header -q "name = 'PGBAK' and trashed = false" | grep -o '^[^ ]*'`"

if [ -z "$PGBAK" ]; then
  PGBAK="`gdrive mkdir PGBAK | head -n 1 | sed 's/^Directory \([^ ]*\) created$/\1/'`"

  if [ -z "$PGBAK" ]; then
    echo "Can't create the PGBAK folder in the Google Drive" >2
    exit 1
  fi
fi

sudo -iu postgres pg_dumpall -g | xz -9 > "$BAK"/globals.sql.xz

# get files ids
GF="`gdrive list --no-header -q "'$PGBAK' in parents and trashed = false" | grep '\sglobals.sql' | head -n 1 | grep -o '^\w*'`"

if [ -z "$GF" ]; then
  # upload file
  gdrive upload --no-progress -p "$PGBAK" "$BAK"/globals.sql.xz > /dev/null
else
  # a revision list can be queried as follows:
  # gdrive revision list --no-header "$GF"

  # update an existing file (revision will be stored for 30 days)
  gdrive update --no-progress "$GF" "$BAK"/globals.sql.xz > /dev/null
fi

# backup all databases individually, in script mode
sudo -iu postgres psql -Atc 'select datname from pg_database order by 1' |\
  while read db; do
    # echo "Backing up $db..."
    DBF="$BAK/$db.sql"
    sudo -iu postgres pg_dump -C "$db" | xz -9 -T 4 > "$DBF.xz"

    GF="`gdrive list --no-header -q "'$PGBAK' in parents and trashed = false" | grep "\\s$DBF" | head -n 1 | grep -o '^\w*'`"

    if [ -z "$GF" ]; then
      # upload file
      gdrive upload --no-progress -p "$PGBAK" "$DBF.xz" > /dev/null
    else
      # you can get the revision list as follows:
      # gdrive revision list --no-header "$GF"

      # update an existing file (revision will be stored for 30 days)
      gdrive update --no-progress "$GF" "$DBF.xz" > /dev/null
    fi
  done
```